# how to modify RoundRobinRouter to RoundRobinPool or RoundRobinGroup in akka(scala)

Tags: scala, akka, router, actor

In my previous codes, RoundRobinRouter (in akka version 2.11-2.3.10) was employed.

```
 val workerRouter = context.actorOf(Props(new DistanceCalculatingWork(frag)).withRouter(RoundRobinRoutor(groups)),name="workerRouter")
```

When I used the new version of akka (v2.54), the codes were insteaded by

```
val workerRouter = context.actorOf(
            Props(new DistanceCalculatingWork(frag)).withRouter(RoundRobinPool(groups)), name = "workerRouter")
```

or

```
val workerRouter = context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(groups).props(Props(new DistanceCalculatingWork(frag))), name = "workerRouter")
```

but the actors could not run, and INFO reported:

```
[INFO] [02/28/2018 17:42:40.202] [CalculateDistances-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://CalculateDistances/user/DistanceCalculatingActor_Master] Message [com.panyl.protax.distance.DistanceActorCounter] from Actor[akka://CalculateDistances/user/DistanceCalculatingActor_Master/workerRouter/$h#2021427677] to Actor[akka://CalculateDistances/user/DistanceCalculatingActor_Master#-384110236] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

What the problem is? And how to fix it?

Comment: Message indicates that the actor `akka://CalculateDistances/user/DistanceCalculatingActor_Master#-384110236` is not running. Try to look for a reason why this actor has stopped.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem has been fixed.